# How to add animation to a queue dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have the following case: I have a circle uiview object, I get new point every 1 second for example. I animate the movement from current position of the uiview to the new point, animation duration depends on distance, so the animation duration could be 500 milli seconds or more than 3 seconds. So please consider the following hand drawn (through ipad sorry) graph:

[image]

In case ‘A’, if I had points in the same direction, I have no problem in sequence of the animation.

But in case ‘B’, that’s my problem; if I animated the circle from point 3 to point 4, and it takes for ex 5 seconds, and after 1 second I receive point 5, a new animation starts from point 4 to point 5, and resulted animation will be something like the red line.

I need a way to add add animations like queue, and searched a lot with no result.

My current approach is something like the following:

```
var animationPoints = [CGPoint]()
var isAnimating = false

func animate(nextPoint) {

    animationPoints.append(nextPoint)

    if !isAnimating {
        isAnimating = true

        let p = animationPoints.first
        animationPoints.removeFirst

        UIView.animate ({ completed in

            isAnimating = false

            if animationPoints.count > 0 {
                animate(animationPoints.first)
            }
        })

    }
}
```

But its not working properly, it skips few points, and slows animation

Comment: how do you call  the animate() method, are you using a for loop

Comment: I call the method when I get new point, but if it is already animating, I call it in Uiview.animate completion handler

Comment: is this your complete animation code ? Seems weird as you're not controlling the flag `isAnimating` neither showing the animate params to let us reproduce.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add     isAnimating flag control to the code in question, please check the edit. Animate param is CGPoint type, although its semi pseudo code.

Comment: Your pseudo-code seems like the right approach. You need to post your real code if you want help debugging it.

Comment: Problem is that the real code is connected to multiple things, but this is the part of animation. Do you think that this approach can be enhanced? Or use a native function maybe with specific options?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to implement what seems to be your requirement by using a queue of UIViewPropertyAnimator objects, each one linked to the previous one through the previous one's completion handler, much as suggested in your pseudocode. The reason I did it that way is that it is possible to add a completion handler to a UIViewPropertyAnimator object at any time, including after the animator has started animating.

To test, I arranged artificially for a series of points to arrive at intervals in real time:

```
var points = [
    CGPoint(x: 60, y: 50),
    CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50),
    CGPoint(x: 150, y: 50),
    CGPoint(x: 150, y: 100),
    CGPoint(x: 250, y: 100)
]
@IBAction func doButton(_ sender: Any) {
    func nextPoint() {
        self.animateToPoint(points.removeFirst())
        if !points.isEmpty {
            delay(0.25) {
                nextPoint()
            }
        }
    }
    nextPoint()
}
```

Each time a point arrives (i.e. each time `self.animateToPoint` is called), I create a new UIViewPropertyAnimator and set the *previous* UIViewPropertyAnimator's `completionHandler` to call `startAnimating()` on the new one. Thus the chain is extended in real time while the animation is ongoing.

In accordance with your requirements, the `duration` of each animation is calculated based on the distance we have to travel to the next point, so that the rate is constant. I deliberately chose a slow constant rate to make the behavior clear.

The result is that, even though the animation is already ongoing when all but the first point arrives, we pass at a constant rate through all the points. To clarify what's going on, I had each completion handler also flash the view red, so you know when the next animation is starting. Thus we see clearly that each animation starts exactly as the previous animation's target point is reached — which, I think, is what you said you wanted to do.

[image]

Comment: Problem is that I don't know the points in advance, so I need the animation to be smooth dynamically by enhancing the logic itself.